# how to create two tables in one SQLite DB by two SqliteHelpers

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have two `SQLiteOpenHelper` classes:

```
public class SQLiteHelper1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = PublicMacros.My_DB;

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";


public class SQLiteHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = PublicMacros.My_DB;

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table2";
```

When I use `SQLiteHelper1` followed by `SQLiteHelper2` I get an error saying:

```
no such table "table2"
```

How can I create the two tables from two different SqliteHelpers?

Comment: Why two `SQLiteHelper`? create both `Table` separately in same `DB`.

Comment: @us Execute two separate `db.execSQL(create table commnad);` for two tables  like `db.execSQL(table1)`; and `db.execSQL(table2);`

Comment: but how to do it organized? create dummy helper just for creating all the tables?

Comment: but why?? simply execute both in your `SQLiteHelper1`

Comment: because who knows tomorrow the calling order won't change and I call SQLiteHelper2 before SQLiteHelper1? they are independant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` manages database files. One helper to manage one database file.

If you want two database helpers, you need them to use different database files.

If you just want two tables in the same database file, put them in the same helper. This is usually the desired way.

> but then it becomes too messy

Nothing prevents you from organizing your code cleanly. For example, you can still use separate classes for different tables. Just don't make them `SQLiteOpenHelper`s but classes that are called by the single `SQLiteOpenHelper` per database file.

Comment: I have thought to create one DB for my app, and create tables for different topics. Isn't that an overhead to create a whole DB for one table?

Comment: but then it becomes too messy. I have thought to create generic CRUD methods per table